# Command \maketitle Vertical Alignment independent of other page content

Tags: positioning, titles

I want to create a `.sty` package for the titlepage layout our university requires for submitted papers.

The main title should always be placed in the same position, regardless of the length of text before or after.

```
\ProvidesPackage{titlepageFormat}[2017-10-17 v0.1]
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
Header\\    
\vspace{5cm}    
\centering
{\large Title\\}
\vspace{3cm}
\raggedright
\vfill
Author\\
\vspace{1.5cm}
Footer\\
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{titlepage}
}
\endinput
```

Suppose this is a minimal working example of my `.sty` file. My goal is to place the "Title" in an absolute position regardless of how many lines "Header" and "Footer" consist of.

In the current example, the "Title" position does not change with increasing header line size because of the `\vfill` at the bottom, but does so when footer line size increases.

Is there any way I can put this into some kind of box and set absolute positions for specific text areas? Just like one would do with letterheads or other stuff that has to be in a specific position. I am using KOMA-Script by the way.

Comment: No problem with tikz or esopic or ... But you will get some complaints by users who have many lines above or below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One  possibility is to use package [`textpos`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) to insert text or images to a page.  For example with

```
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(50mm,75mm) % {〈hsize〉}[〈ho〉,〈vo〉](〈hpos〉,〈vpos〉)
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}% a full-page picture?
\end{textblock*}%
```

you include an image with a width of `100mm`, starting at point `(50mm,75mm)`.

See the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(50mm,75mm) % {〈hsize〉}[〈ho〉,〈vo〉](〈hpos〉,〈vpos〉)
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}% a full-page picture?
\end{textblock*}%
Header\\    
\vspace{5cm}    
\centering
{\large Title\\}
\vspace{3cm}
\raggedright
\vfill
Author\\
\vspace{1.5cm}
Footer\\
\vspace{1.5cm}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

with its result:

[image: resulting titlepage]

Change the values `(50mm,75mm)` to your needs ...